# An Integral of a Bessel function

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, residue-calculus, bessel-functions

I have an integral of $\
R_{1} =-i\int_{t}^{\infty }\frac{ds}{s}J_{1}\left( 2s\right) e^{i\nu s}$,

where $J_{1}\left( 2s\right)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. and $t$ is a positive number.

I try to solve it in the following method:

$\frac{dR_{1}}{d\nu }=\int_{t}^{\infty }dsJ_{1}\left( 2s\right) e^{i\nu s}
$

$\
J_{n}\left( x\right) =\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }e^{i\left( x\sin
\theta -n\theta \right) }d\theta$

$\frac{dR_{1}}{d\nu }=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }d\theta
\int_{t}^{\infty }dse^{i\left( 2s\sin \theta -\theta \right) }e^{i\nu s}=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }d\theta \frac{
-e^{-i\left[ \theta -t\left( 2\sin \theta +\nu \right) \right] }}{i\left(
2\sin \theta +\nu \right)} 
$

Using the Jacobi-Anger expansion $\
e^{ix\sin \theta }=\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }J_{n}\left( x\right)
e^{in\theta }
$,

$\frac{dR_{1}}{d\nu } =\frac{1}{2\pi }e^{it\nu }\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }J_{n}\left( 2t\right)
\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }d\theta \frac{-e^{-i\theta }e^{in\theta }}{i\left( 2\sin
\theta +\nu \right) }$

Taking $\
z=e^{i\theta }$
, $dz=ie^{i\theta }d\theta =izd\theta$, and $\sin \theta =\frac{e^{i\theta }-e^{-i\theta }}{2i}=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$, I get

$\frac{dR_{1}}{d\nu }=-e^{it\nu }\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }J_{n}\left( 2t\right) \frac{1}{2\pi
i}\oint dz\frac{z^{n-1}}{z^{2}+i\nu z-1}$

According to the residue theorem, if $n>1$, then suppose there is only a single pole with $\left\vert z_{+}\right\vert <1$, while $n\leq 0$ there is also a pole at $z=0$.

$\frac{1}{z^{2}+i\nu z-1}=\frac{1}{\left( z-z_{+}\right) \left(
z-z_{-}\right) }$, $z_{\pm }=\frac{-i\nu \pm \sqrt{\left( i\nu \right) ^{2}+4}}{2}$

$\frac{1}{\left( z-z_{+}\right) \left( z-z_{-}\right) }=\frac{1}{z_{+}-z_{-}}%
\left[ \frac{1}{z-z_{+}}-\frac{1}{z-z_{-}}\right]$

For $z$ near $0$,
$\frac{1}{z-z_{+}} =\frac{-1}{z_{+}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{z_{+}}}
=\left( \frac{-1}{z_{+}}\right) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\left( \frac{z}{z_{+}}%
\right) ^{j}$, so

$\frac{dR_{1}}{d\nu }=-e^{it\nu }\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }J_{n}\left( 2t\right) \frac{1}{2\pi
i}\oint dz\frac{z^{n-1}}{z^{2}+i\nu z-1}$

$=-e^{it\nu }\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }J_{n}\left( 2t\right)
I_{n}+\sum_{n=-\infty }^{0}J_{n}\left( 2t\right) I_{n}\right) $

$=-e^{it\nu }\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }J_{n}\left( 2t\right) \frac{\left(
z_{+}\right) ^{n-1}}{z_{+}-z_{-}}\right. +\left. \sum_{n=-\infty
}^{0}J_{n}\left( 2t\right) \left[ \frac{-1}{z_{+}-z_{-}}\left( \frac{1}{%
\left( z_{+}\right) ^{1-n}}-\frac{1}{\left( z_{-}\right) ^{1-n}}\right) +%
\frac{\left( z_{+}\right) ^{n-1}}{z_{+}-z_{-}}\right] \right\}$.

Because I seperate the sum into two parts from $-\infty$ to $0$ and from $1$ to $+\infty$, how can I combine them again to obtain the results? Do I make any mistakes during the calculations? I have been struggling for a couple of weeks. Also, do you have some better methods to solve this integral? Many thanks!

Comment: Integral identities of Bessel functions on intervals that aren't $[0,\infty)$ are few and far between... I doubt there's a better way to do this other than numerically.